# PHP framwework, multiple sites and httpd and DNS

Tags: dns, apache-httpd

I'm wondering if this is possible:

There is a PHP framework and someone made several sites, which can be accessible like this:

`.../index.php/aaa`
`.../index.php/ccc`

I would like to somehow map DNS to point to each site independently, for example:

`aaa.domain.com` -> `index.php/aaa`
`ccc.domain.com` -> `index.php/ccc`

But `DocumentRoot` can't be specified this way. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using URL rewriting inside Apache. Other servers likely have the same functionality available, I just don't have personal experience with other servers.